# Updating all of Windows Drivers

Tags: windows-8, drivers, updates

I recently had Linux Mint running as my sole OS, which I later decided to remove to reinstall Windows 8. Windows Update is current, however after the installation I found some missing functionality (USB ports, FN Keys, etc.).

I want my computer to run as if I just bought it. Is there a one-stop shop to ensure that all of my Windows drivers are up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the manufacturer and model for each of your devices you could search for drivers on the support pages of each manufacturer.

Otherwise you can use a software like [3DP Chip](http://www.3dpchip.com/3dpchip/3dp/chip_down_en.php) which detects your hardware and gives you links to download drivers.

[image]

Comment: I would come back and down-vote this answer if I could (not enough reputation). 3DChip is buggy software that just threw a runtime exception!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install any software to update your drivers, then you can do it via the internet safely by visiting [This Link](http://www.touslesdrivers.com/index.php?v_page=29) and launching the detection, it is so simple.

+1 if it helped, thank you.